# How to pass nested values on has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following method that check if a person has an integration by number and carrier and if not match an integration by number only.

```
class Person
  has_one :number

  def integration
    number_and_carrier = Integration.where('number_id = ? and carrier_id = ?', number.id, carrier.id) if number && carrier
    Integration.where('number_id = ?', number.id) if number && number_and_carrier.nil?
  end

end
```

The following code works ok. But I wonder how could I accomplish the same using a `has_one` association so I can have full control over the integration object returned. I can imagine starting with something like this

```
has_one :integration, foreign_key: :number_id
```

But I quickly realise this is using the current `person_id` (7750) and not the `number_id`.

```
SELECT "integrations".* FROM "integrations" WHERE "integrations"."number_id" = 7750 LIMIT 1
```

My questions are

1. How can I pass the `number.id` to the `has_one` association?
2. How can the `has_one` query can keep the method query (check if a person has an integration by number and carrier and if not match an integration by number only)

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from your code, instead of setting `:foreign_key`, I think, you need to set `:primary_key => :number_id`